# PCL addLine in Qt crashes application

Tags: c++, qt, point-cloud-library

I'm building a PCL viewer in Qt and have successfully replicated the demo application found on the PCL site (http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/qt_visualizer.php)

I built vtk 5.8 to generate the qvtkWidget.

The demo builds and runs fine, all the controls work and points are drawn correctly. Now I need to draw other items, spheres, lines, etc.

I use the viewer->addLine() function... in Visual Studio it works fine.
However, in Qt (4.8.5), whenever I try to do anything else it kills the program!

The Application output window in QT reports the following

Starting C:\xxx\build\release\pcltest.exe...
The program has unexpectedly finished.
C:\xxx\build\release\pcltest.exe crashed

The only functions that appear to work are

```
addPointCloud()
removePointCloud()
```

All the following cause it to crash

```
setBackgroundColor()
addCoordinateSystem()
addLine()
addSphere()
```

Any ideas...?

Comment: What is the difference between "in Visual Studio" and "in Qt"? Isn't the code the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the Qt visualizer tutorial code;

Add a new button in the UI (`pushButton_sphere`), then connect the signal to a new member function:

```
connect (ui->pushButton_sphere,  SIGNAL (clicked ()), this, SLOT (sphereButtonPressed ()));
```

The member function should look like this:

```
void
PCLViewer::sphereButtonPressed ()
{
  printf ("Sphere button was pressed\n");
  viewer->addSphere(pcl::PointXYZ(0, 0, 0), 1.0);
  viewer->addLine(pcl::PointXYZ(2, 0, 0), pcl::PointXYZ(1, 1, 1));
  viewer->addCube(Eigen::Vector3f(2, 0, 0), Eigen::Quaternionf::Identity(), 1, 1, 1);
  viewer->setBackgroundColor(.2, 0, 0);
  ui->qvtkWidget->update();
}
```

I have tested lines, spheres, cubes and background color on Ubuntu 14.04 + PCL 1.7.2 (from PPA) + VTK 5.8. If that codes crashes it is probably platform specific so please debug and [fill a bug on the PCL tracker](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/new).

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing this exact same problem.

From the experimentation I have done so far, it seems that if you try and add more than one element imediately after creating the PCLVisualizer, then the application crashes.

In the example application, the additional elements are added only after the user presses a button. This means that there is both a time delay between creating and adding elements, but also there is the ability for the Qt application to process other events on the event queue.

I hoven't got to the bottom of this yet but my guess is that calling update() on the visualiser after creating it results in some events to be placed on the event queue. trying add more stuff before these are processed causes the crash.

The problem is in my code I need to start adding things straight away and I have no mechanism to determine when it's safe to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that VTK installation path has been put in your global environment. Since QT can't find it, it will probably crash.